# "Toggle Breakpoint Enabled" is disabled, JetBrains

Tags: node.js, breakpoints, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to debug a nodejs application with WebStorm, but cant set breakpoints.
I guess it is because "Toggle Breakpoint Enabled" is not activated. I cant activate it.
What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: 'Toggle breakpoint enabled' is only enabled if the cursor is placed on the line with breakpoint; to create a breakpoint, just click in the left gutter. See https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/creating-breakpoints.html